# Installation and setting hadoop on fedora 29

Tags: hadoop, fedora

I am trying to install `Hadoop` on `Fedora 29` and while doing so I encountered with an error as shown below:

```
[hdadmin@single-node-pseudo-cluster ~]$ vi .bashrc
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.191.b12-11.fc29.x86_64/
export HADOOP_PREFIX= /usr/local/hadoop-3.2.0/
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$HADOOP_PREFIX/bin


[hdadmin@single-node-pseudo-cluster ~]$ source ~/.bashrc
bash: export: `/usr/local/hadoop-3.2.0/': not a valid identifier


    -[the image shows the path of jdk folder][1]
    -[the image shows the path of hadoop folder][2]
    -Please help me to solve the error, thank you.
     [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6p949.png
     [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iefV.png
```

Comment: Try to delete space before path at HADOOP_PREFIX, cause the correct syntax to assign a variable is NAME=value. 
`export HADOOP_PREFIX=/usr/local/hadoop-3.2.0/`

Comment: I'll be grateful if you vote on or accept the answer.
[What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete space before path at HADOOP_PREFIX, because the correct syntax to assign a variable is `NAME=value`.
So, right option: `export HADOOP_PREFIX=/usr/local/hadoop-3.2.0/`